# Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have trouble when open my web and its said Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object and i cant figure out how to solve it. i hope any of you guys can help me out.

so this is my web controller

```
 <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

     class Web extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        $data = array(
            "produk_populers" => $this->mymodel->GetProduk()->result_array()

    );

    $comp = array(
        "header" => $this->load->view("header",array(),true),
        "navbar" => $this->load->view("navbar",array(),true),
        "iklan" => $this->load->view("iklan",array(),true),
        "produk_populer" => $this->load->view("produk_populer",$data,true),
        "kategori" => $this->load->view("kategori",array(),true),
        "footer" => $this->load->view("footer",array(),true),

    );

    $this->load->view("index",$comp);

    }

    public function html_produk_populer(){
        $data = array(
            "produk_populer" => $this->mymodel->GetProduk()
    );
        return $this->load->view("produk_populer",$data,true);

    }



}
```

and this is my produk_populer.php

```
    <div class="allcontain">
    <div class="feturedsection">
    <h1 class="text-center"><span class="bdots">&bullet;</span>P R O D U K<span class="carstxt">P O P U L E R</span>&bullet;</h1>
  </div>


    <div class="feturedimage">
        <div class="row firstrow">
            <div class="col-lg-6 costumcol colborder1">
                <div class="row costumrow">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 img1colon">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url()."assets/"; ?>images/<?php echo $produk_populer['gambar_produk']; ?>" alt="floridina">
                    </div>

                <?php foreach ($produk_populers as $produk_populer) { ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 txt1colon">
                        <div class="featurecontant">
                            <h1><?php echo $produk_populer['nama_produk']; ?></h1>
                            <p><?php echo $produk_populer['info_produk']; ?></p>
                            <h1><?php echo $produk_populer['harga_produk']; ?></h1>
                            <!--<<button id="btnRM" onClick="rmtxt()">READ MORE</button>
                            <div id="readmore">
                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <p><br>
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <br>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ,<br>
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur1 ,
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur1
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur1<br>
                                    </p>
                                    <button id="btnRL">READ LESS</button>
                            </div>-->

                        </div>

                    </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>


                <!--<div class="col-lg-6 costumcol colborder2">
                <div class="row costumrow">
                <?php //foreach ($produk_populers as $produk_populer) { ?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 img2colon">
                        <img src="<?php //echo base_url()."assets/"; ?>images/<?php //echo $produk_populer['gambar_produk']; ?>" alt="floridina">
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 txt1colon ">
                        <div class="featurecontant">
                            <h1><?php //echo $produk_populer['nama_produk']; ?></h1>
                            <p><?php //echo $produk_populer['info_produk']; ?></p>
                            <h1><?php //echo $produk_populer['harga_produk']; ?></h1>

                            <div id="readmore">
                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <p><br>
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt <br>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur ,<br>
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur1 ,
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur1
                                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur1<br>
                                    </p>
                                    <button id="btnRL">READ LESS</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                </div> -->

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

also this is mymodel.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mymodel extends CI_Model {
public function GetProduk($where=""){
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from produk');
    return $data -> result_array();

}



}
```

so that is all i need to ask, i hope theres anyone who can help me. Thanks

Comment: Show us the code for the class `GetProduk()`

Comment: You have not mentioned model code so mention first

Comment: this is the model code. i named it mymodel.php

Comment: Did you try var_dump $this->db? What I am questioning if you did load DB somewhere or not,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work assuming you have loaded DB class.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mymodel extends CI_Model {
public function GetProduk($where=""){
    $data = $this->db->query('select * from produk');
    return $data;

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->mymodel->GetProduk()->result_array();
```

`$this->mymodel` is not working. You didn't load model. You have to load mymodel before call it by using `$this->load->model('mymodel')`. Or also you can load it from globally by using autoload.php

Comment: but i already load it by using autoload.php but it still wont work. thanks for the fast answer

Comment: What is returning by your GetProduk() function? Is it an object of db? Can you give us that function or details?

Comment: $this->mymodel->GetProduk()->result_array() this will work only if $this->mymodel->GetProduk() returns object of db e.g return $this->db->get('banks');

Comment: i already edited my post and there is the model code. is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: You are already returning `return $data -> result_array();` So why you again calling `result_array()`. `$this->mymodel->GetProduk()` is returning an array to you. Just use it. no need of calling this `$this->mymodel->GetProduk()->result_array();` Call only `$this->mymodel->GetProduk();`